# Date data is displaying correctly in the console but is saved incorrectly in the object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

As seen below, the x(date) property of unopened objects in the console are correct until I open them and the real data is revealed to be:

> Mon Jun 06 2016 16:19:28 GMT+1000 (AEST)

Why is this happening?

[image]

---

My code basically gets an array of orders with variable dates. It groups them in consistent time ranges with getDataInRange. Then reduces those time ranges to an average with getAverageInRange.

1. getDataInRange(objects:array, startRange:integer, endRange:integer)
2. getAverageInRange(objectsWithinInterval:array, currentTimeMiliseconds:integer,timePositionToSet:integer)
3. normaliseData(objects:array, millisecondInterval:integer)

---

```
var getDataInRange = function (data, start, end) {
    return data.filter(function (eachThing) {
        var currentDate = new Date(eachThing.created_at).getTime();
        return currentDate >= start && currentDate <= end;
    })
}

var getAverageInRange = function (range, time, interval) {

    // if there is no data
    if (range.length <= 0) {
        return null;
    }

    var avgPrice = range.map(function (order) {
        return parseFloat(order.price)
    }).reduce(function (current, next) {
        return current + next;
    }, 0);

    priceTime = {
        x: new Date(interval),
        y: avgPrice,
    }
    return priceTime
}

var normaliseData = function (data, interval) {

    var results = [];

    var start =  new Date(data[0].created_at).getTime();
    var end = new Date(data[data.length - 1].created_at).getTime()
    var range = end - start;
    var startRange;
    var prevAverage = null;


    // loop
    // this will loop through each interval
    for ( let i = start; i < end; i += interval) {

        var currentDatePoint = i - (interval/2)
        // GET START RANGE

        if (i >= interval * 2) {
            startRange = i - interval;
        } else {
            startRange = 0;
        }

        var range = getDataInRange(data, startRange, i);

        var average = getAverageInRange(range, i, currentDatePoint);


        if ( average === null ){
            prevAverage.x = new Date(currentDatePoint);
            average = prevAverage;
        }

        console.log(average);
        results.push(average);
        prevAverage = average;
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a duplicate of the average variable instead of assigning the variable itself fixed this for me.

Changed:

```
prevAverage = average;
```

To:

```
prevAverage = duplicateObject(average);

var duplicateObject = (object) => {
        var obj = {}
        for (var key in object) {
            obj[key] = object[key]
        }
        return obj;
    }
```